# wordpress custom theme option

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom wordpress theme with a little bit of backend admin system.

Why I need to declare

```
global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
}
```

multiple times in header and footer? Because my index.php file includes header.php and footer.php.
Why can't I declare one time at the header.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it has to do with your usage of `$options` and variable scope. While you'll probably need `global $options` wherever you want to use that variable, you probably only need the foreach loop there only the first time.

Also, `get_settings()` is deprecated, use `get_options()` instead.

Comment: `get_option()`, not `get_options()` - and its no biggie calling this multiple times in a page load since the result is cached the first time and then pulled from cache the subsequent times. There's no extra database hits calling `get_option` as many times as you want.